# How to make a search in filesystem-like structure in Haskell

Tags: file, haskell, search

**problem**

I have a Type:

```
data FSObject = Folder String [FSObject] | File String
```

and I need to make a function

```
search :: String -> FSObject -> Maybe String
```

that returns a path to File that we are searching for (if exists)
(String in search function should be equal to the name (the String in File object (w/o path)) of the searched File.

**my thoughts/tryings**

I feel like I am not doing it properly- in a functional way. I am new to this language so I am sorry for the following code.

I was trying to do this for several hours. I was trying like this:

heler function contains that returns true if given FSObject contains File that we are looking for

helper function that returns first element with the File (using previous function and "find" function)

helper function to deal with conversion from Maybe String to String

My search function would check if there is the File, if no-> return Nothing, else return Just with String computed somehow using recursion

I can paste my work but I don't know how to make it work, its totally unreadable etc.

Do some1 has hints/comments to share? How to properly deal with Maybe in this kind of problems?

Comment: What is the first String in the `search` function?  Full filename (including path separators), partial filename, filename with path part removed, search string inside contents?

Comment: name of file w/o path (the String in File object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using recursion.

```
findPath::String->FSObject->Maybe String
findPath name (File name') | name == name' = Just name
findPath _ (File _) = Nothing
findPath name (Folder path contents) = 
             fmap ((path ++ "/") ++) $ msum $ map (findPath name) contents
```

The only tricky point is the last part.  Breaking the last line apart....

```
map (findPath name) contents
```

will output a list of subresults

```
[Just "a/b/filename", Nothing, Just "c/d/filename", ....]
```

`msum` will take the first Just in the list, throwing the rest away (and, by laziness, nothing further than that first value will actually be created)

Finally, the path is prepended (the `fmap` is there to reach inside the `Maybe`)

Answer (score 1):

While @jamshidh solution is short, it isn't modular and the final result. Here is my process of writing the program. Two main points:

- I'll use so called "generate then search" approach: first I generate paths for all files, then I search the collection for the right path
- I'll store path as list of components - this way the code will be more generic (in Haskell more generic code is less error-prone) and I will insert path separators afterwards in a small function (so I can do one thing at a time which is easier).

Ok I need function allPaths that gives me list of all files along with their paths. All paths of a single file is that single file, and all paths of a folder is concatenated collections of paths from children with prepended folder name:

```
allPaths (File file) = singleFile file
allPaths (Folder folder children) = concatMap (addFolder folder . allPaths) children
```

I actually wrote the code top-down. So I didn't bother defining `singleFile` and `addFolder` at this point. Single file is simple:

```
singleFile file = [(file, [])]
```

`addFolder` adds `f` to second component of a tuple. There is a function in `Control.Arrow` for that already, but I add its implementation here for simplicity:

```
second f (a,x) = (a, f x)

addFolder f files = map (second (f:)) files
```

When I was learning Haskell it was hard to write such code at once, but now it's automatic and without intermediate steps.

Now we basically implement `search` by filtering all matching files, taking the first match and extracting the path. Oh, there is already function `lookup` in the standard library for that:

```
search fileToSearch l = lookup fileToSearch $ allPaths l
```

It took me quite a while to figure out how to compose `lookup` and `allPaths`. Fortunately the order in the tuple was chosen correctly by accident.

Note that you still need to convert folder list to a path by inserting separators and appending filename as necessary using `concatMap`.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a recursive function using an accumulation parameter to save the current path where you're searching. It would be something like this:

```
    search str (File f) = if str == f then Just str else Nothing
    search str (Directory dir (x:xs)) = 
       Just (sear str [] (Directory dir (x:xs))) where
            sear str path (File f) = if str == f then (path ++ "/" ++ str ++ "|") else []
            sear str path (Directory y []) = []
            sear str path (Directory dir (x:xs)) = sear str (path ++ "/" ++ dir) x ++ sear str path (Directory dir xs)
```

I hope it's helpful for you.